# "Relation" versus "relationship"

Tags: word-choice, meaning

What is the difference between *relation* and *relationship*?

Some say that *relationship* often refers to social connections. For instance,

> She has a close relationship with her daughter.

How about the following?

> the relationship between poor housing and health problems (Longman Dictionary)
>
> the special relationship between Britain and the US (Longman Dictionary)

Comment: From an Natural Language Processing standpoint, this is a great question.  Relation(ship) extraction is part of the information extraction pipeline.  Stanford calls it relation extraction whereas other places you could conceivably hear the term relationship extraction

Answer (score 48):

While *relation* and *relationship* refer to the connection between things, *relation* shades more toward the *way* things are connected, while *relationship* refers to the connection itself. The difference is not spacious.

Example:

> "The size of the targets bore no relation to their importance." [NOAD]

This is different from

> "The two friends enjoyed a very close relationship."

Comment: Moreover, _relation_ is more formal and has a technical meaning in mathematics.

Comment: @Ganymede perhaps you can answer this [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/341283/mathematical-distinction-in-relation-between-edges-vs-relationship-between-ed) on the mathematical distinction.

Comment: Did you mean "not specious"?

Comment: @CPerkins: Nope. It was a conscious nod to Mark Twain, from his essay on Fenimore Cooper's Literary Offenses: "In that matter of intellect, the difference between a Cooper Indian and the Indian that stands in front of the cigar-shop is **not spacious**. " Meaning not a lot.

Comment: How would "The two friends enjoyed a very close relation" differ from "The two friends enjoyed a very close relationship"?

Comment: @NicolasSchmidt: You wouldn't use *relation* in that context. Use *relationship* instead.

Comment: @Robusto Why? P.S.: At least some people do use it in that context: Google search for "enjoyed a close relation" returns many results.

Comment: @NicolasSchmidt: Google searches are notorious for turning up erroneous and ungrammatical constructions.

Comment: @Robusto Some of these search results are published books by native English speakers.

Comment: @NicolasSchmidt: Without putting too fine a point on it, you'd have to cite those instances, with text, for anyone to discuss them with you. And since comments are not meant for discussion, perhaps you'd be better off giving your own answer to this question along with an argument including the evidence you think supports it.

Comment: @Robusto Why do you think that "relation" shouldn't be used in the example I mentioned? Is the sentence "The two friends enjoyed a very close relation" meaningless in your opinion? If not, how does its meaning differ from "The two friends enjoyed a very closed relationship"?

Answer (score 13):

To me, the main difference is that *relationship* is broader than *relation*:

- both can mean “the way in which two or more concepts, objects, or people are connected”;
- in addition, *relationship* can mean “the state of being connected”.

So, in “She has a close relationship with her daughter”, because you're talking about the fact a particular existing connection, I wouldn't use “relation”.

In your second example, if “the relationship between poor housing and health problems” is merely an academic study of the possible correlation, then “relation” would fit well.

In the third, again, the “special relationship” is a particular, existing connection, so “relation” wouldn't fit the bill. In addition, “[special relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_Relationship)” is a well established phrase since post-World War II times.

Answer (score 4):

There's other meanings as well...

"Fred has had [sexual] relations with Sally."

"I hate having to invite my poor relations to parties, because they always steal the silverware."

In the database sense, without being pedantic about the academically correct definitions of "Relation" and "Relationship", especially at the physical level when we are discussing tables (not tuples) but in keeping with the English meaning ...

- A real (table) or derived (columns from more than one table) is a Relation

  - but most developers will cringe at, it is not commonly understood
  - therefore we commonly call them tables or derived tables
- and therefore the Relationships can be simply Relations between tables

  - both defined (as Foreign Keys) and not (derived, as per other data values, such as related by date or time or some other value)
  - personally I would capitalise the formally defined Relations and leave the derived or projected relations uncapitalised.

Comment: Re „_at the physical level when we are discussing tables (not tuples)_“ – Why do you contrast _tables_ with _tuples?_  A _table_ is the physical pendant of a model _relation_, a _tuple_ is the model pendant of a physical _record_, aren't they?

Answer (score -4):

*Relationship* means "bond" while *relation* means "connection", used in formal and informal lexicon.

Comment: Since a bond is a connection, this is not really helpful. (Not to mention how this one-liner compares to the older answers.)